# Integrate a Dash app with a route into a proper running Flask environment

Tags: flask, plotly-dash

I'm struggling a bit with integrating a proper running Dash app inside a Flask website. Either I do have a problem in understanding howit works or it's only a small issue.
Each hint is welcome.

- My Flask environment has this route:

```
@blueprint.route('/dash-test')
@login_required
def dash_test():
    """Integrate the Dash App into the page"""
    server = flask.Flask(__name__)
    return render_template('dashapp-test.html',
                           my_dashapp=my_dash_app(),
                           server=server
                           )
```

- It's calling the function which contains the Dash app:

```
def my_dash_app():

    app = dash.Dash(
        __name__,
        external_stylesheets=['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'],
    )

    app.layout = html.Div(id='example-div-element')
    return app
```

- Given result after send the request /dash-test:

*<dash.dash.Dash object at 0x0000025909864700>*

But expected is: Dash App is shown.

Comment: Dash is itself a Flask app, so I'm not sure how exactly it would work putting it inside another Flask app. Have you tried returning `app.run_server()`?

Comment: `app.run_server()` doesn't work: http header are showing me the request is coming in properly, but the browser didn't get any response. @coralvanda

Comment: If `app` is your flask app, then `app.run_server()` will work @coralvanda --> but if `app` is your dashapp, it will not...

Comment: You're right @YaakovBressler . I just retried it and can see: app.run_server() has started http://127.0.0.1:8050/dash-test/ in parallel to the running Flask which stays accesible under http://127.0.0.1:5000

Comment: Flask apps are like onions... (layers) @squeezer44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something to keep in mind: when you generate a dashapp, you are adding components to an existing flask application (also called "server"). A suitable solution to this would be to build your flask app --> then build your dash app with a specific route --> then build a route in your flask app to your dashapp:

```py
# Create a function which creates your dashapp
import dash
def create_dashapp(server):
    app = dash.Dash(
        server=server,
        url_base_pathname='/dashapp/'
    )
    app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True
    app.title='Dash App'

    # Set the layout
    app.layout = layout = html.Div('Hello Dash app')

    # Register callbacks here if you want...
    
    return app


# Create your app (or server, same thing really)
server = flask.Flask(__name__)

# Initialize by passing through your function
create_dashapp(server)

# Define index route
@server.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello Flask app'


# Define dashapp route
@server.route('/dashapp/')
@login_required
def redirect_to_dashapp():
    return redirect('/dashapp/')


# Finally run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Because I do have an already running Flask environment as the request is coming in your approach work 50%: Both environments are up but under different ports (=50%), they are existing both benear bot ot together). But it's working perfectly in case Dash App and Flask are running under the same port (this is the case if both are starting together). @Yaakov Bressler

Comment: You can specify different ports if you like, though that opens a can of worms..

Answer (score 3):

[This page](https://dash.plotly.com/integrating-dash) from the docs might prove useful for you. It deals directly with running Dash inside a Flask app. Here is the mini example they provide:

```py
import flask
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

server = flask.Flask(__name__)

@server.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello Flask app'

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    server=server,
    routes_pathname_prefix='/dash/'
)

app.layout = html.Div("My Dash app")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Nice answer! I only read it after creating mine --> we have a very similar approach to solving this. Consensus --> truthiness